# OpenSSLErrorStack: error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React Project but whenever I run it I end up getting errors. Below is the error codes:

```
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v17.0.1
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Any Feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps on your terminal in the current app directory:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

Installs the npm-check-updates package globally for doing exactly what its name says.

```
ncu
```

This will display the dependencies side-by-side with (an arrow pointing to) their new versions (you are advised to upgrade to) as listed in your package.json file in the current directory.

```
ncu -u
```

This updates those new listed versions on your package.json file and prepares your app for the next step (the updates proper).

```
npm update
```

or

```
npm install
```

Either of these 2 finally installs the new updates. It fixes the problems.

---

NB: I used

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Install nvm: https://medium.com/@diego.coder/instalar-nvm-node-version-manager-en-windows-80d6768fa183
- Install Node 16: `nvm install 16`
- Use that version: `nvm use 16`
- Run your project normally